# android home screen widget in 8x7 and 8x5 tablets

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a home screen widget it is designed to work properly in 8x7 tablets(samsung and motorola). Now i want to make the widget to work properly in 8x5 tablets(nexus 10). i have reduced the dimension of the widget to make it working in 8x5. Now how to configure the widget dimensions so that it will work in both 8x7 and 8x5?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your widget provider XML:

android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"

This ensures the user can resize the widget to fit the available screen size. You can also set a default and minimum size.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData